При наличии тире в данном предложении, нужна ли ещё и запятая перед тире?
Как прокомментировали сотрудники – к проверке всё готово.

Правильно:
Как прокомментировали сотрудники – к проверке всё готово.
Пояснение

Сравнить: Как прокомментировали сотрудники, к проверке всё готово.

Это вводное предложение с союзом КАК. У Розенталя: Как выражаются моряки, ветер крепчал (Ч.);

В приведенном предложении интонационное (разделительное) тире заменяет запятую, но не добавляется к ней. Иначе мы получим единый знак, обозначающий увеличенную паузу, характерную для присоединительных  или пояснительных  отношений.


Как прокомментировали сотрудники — в ПАС под редакцией Лопатина о таких конструкциях говорится:

§ 92. Вводные предложения имеют значения, близкие к значениям вводных слов и сочетаний слов. Они выделяются запятыми либо, значительно реже, — знаком тире. Некрасивого, доброго человека, каким он себя считал, можно, полагал он, любить как приятеля (Л. Т.); Как выражаются моряки, ветер крепчал (Ч.); У нее, как говорят писатели, вырвался вздох облегчения (Бел.); Сидят здесь под страхом смерти и — что еще хуже — под проливным дождем (Каз.).

Говорится КОНКРЕТНО: или — запятая, или — тире.
Вот, как мне кажется, подходящий пример:
Жить вместе оказалось куда сподручней, тем более что, вселяясь, квартиранты притащили — как говорила тетя Ксана — «калым»... (Д. Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы).
Стоит отметить, что в Нацкорпусе обособления с помощью тире вводных сочетаний (как прокомментировали, как подумали, как предположили...) не имеется.
Такое пунктуационное решение (с употреблением тире) и вправду нечастое.

ВСТУПЛЕНИЕ
Дам еще один ответ: чем больше ответов, тем лучше.
Ну мне так кажется))
И еще мне кажется, что в начале ответа должен быть ответ. Но увы, никто меня не слушает, и очень часто я ответа не вижу не только в начале, но и вообще.
Вот до чего хорош принцип информативности, не зря же люди его придумали! Да у нас вся литература скоро станет информативной, потому что когда читать-то? Времени нет, все не прочитаешь.
Поэтому сначала ответ, потом совсем краткое пояснение, а потом уже можно писать для души, что хочешь.
А пользователь прочитает то, что ему нужно, и это уважение к нашим читателям. Ну разве нет логики?
ОСНОВНАЯ ЧАСТЬ
  При наличии тире в данном предложении, нужна ли ещё и 
  запятая перед тире? 

Правильно: Как прокомментировали сотрУдники – // к проверке всё готОво.

Итак, тире в авторском варианте уже поставлено. Оставалось сказать, нужна ли дополнительная запятая. В первом ответе я поясняю, почему не нужна. А что еще-то сказать?

Надо объяснить, зачем автору нужно это тире. Действительно, разве запятой нельзя было обойтись?  Все же обходятся и тире ставят значительно реже. Соответствует ли это тире правилам?

Дело в том, что при постановке тире происходит актуализация вводного предложения, то есть дополнительное смысловое выделение логическим ударением. Необходимость такого выделения определяется по контексту. Теперь это не простой источник сообщения, но имеющий в этом предложении дополнительный смысл: вывод о готовности сделан на основании комментариев сотрудников.

Нужны ли примеры?  Может и нужны, но только с такой же структурой и в соответствии с подобным контекстом.



Согласна с вами: вопрошающего в первую очередь интересует, как правильно! Может, ему надо срочно знать и нет времени разбирать теорию. Поэтому он сначала воспользуется предлагаемым ответом, а потом почитает объяснения.

Да,  это так.  Принцип информативности  разработан для сотрудников редакций, где печатается материал по учебным и другим темам. Там с этим делом строго:  нет читателей – нет продаж.
